# Variation with variable count of possibilities

Tags: c#

I have programmed a game where the player has 30 days to build city.
I like to know all the possible approaches the player could take so that i know which is the best one.

Basicly with 30 days and 9 projects which can be bought and upgraded the    mathematical formula would be n^k. Which in our case woud be 9^30 = 42.391.158.275.216.203.514.294.433.201
But because it is a game the projects the player can buy per round depend on variabels like for examples coins. So its something like
 4*1*5*3*2...

My problem is that GameStats, which simulates the game environment, does not get reset when a new buildpath is added.

Example

The player starts with 15 coins and an income of 5. First day he build houses for 10 coins

- day 0: buildpath{house}; coins 15                -> bought house -10 coins
- day 1: buildpath{house, empty}; coins 5          -> no coins to buy anything
- day 2: buildpath{house, empty, house}; coins 10  -> player can buy house, street or cycletrack

now for the next possible buildpath we start at day 2 where could also have bougth the street or the cycletrack and had 10 coins but GameStats which holds the coins is now by 15coins.

How do I keep the GameStats unique for every possible buildpath?

```
public string[] GetPermutation(int days, List<BaseProject> projects)
{

    ArrayList output = new ArrayList();
    GameStats game = new GameStats();
    GetPermutationPerRef(days, projects, ref output, ref game);

    return output.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
}


private void GetPermutationPerRef(int days, List<BaseProject> projects, ref ArrayList output, ref GameStats game, string outputPart = "")
{
    if (days == 0)
    {
        outputPart += " points: " ; 
        output.Add(outputPart);
    }
    else
    {
        if(projects.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (BaseProject p in projects)
            {
                // construct the current project
                game.BuyProject(p);

                // move on to the next day
                game.nextDay();

                // find all the projects the player could buy the next day
                projects = game.GetBuyAbleBaseProjects();

                GetPermutationPerRef(days - 1,          
                    projects,                            
                    ref output,  
                    ref game,                               
                    outputPart + p.projectName +" "); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // dont buy or upgrade any project

            game.nextDay();

            projects = game.GetBuyAbleBaseProjects();

            GetPermutationPerRef(days - 1,
                projects,
                ref output,
                ref game,
                outputPart + "empty ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: dont use `ArrayList`. its obsolete now. in your case use `List<string>` for output. and to return list as array just do this `return output.ToArray();`. another thing. dont pass objects by `ref`. in your case its not necessary. those objects are already reference type so you can remove `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a linked List of Days.  Adding an item to the linked list is a different outcome.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Day> days = new List<Day>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
    public class Day
    {
        int day { get; set; }
        int housesBought { get; set; }
        int money { get; set; }
        List<Day> nextDay = new List<Day>();

    }
}
```